# In Excel how can I replace 6 Zeros with an M?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, microsoft-excel-2013

For example,

- How do I turn $200 000 000 to $200 M.
- How do I turn $12 500 000 to $12.5 M?

I use Excel 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is probably to use custom number format:

`$#,##0.##,, " M"`

(I can't get rid of the decimal point when it isn't necessary)

[image]

For more information see [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25276116/4721734), or [office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4)